# How to test D3 zoom behavior in a React component with React Testing Library and Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to write tests for a React component that uses D3's zoom behavior. I've set up the zoom behavior inside a useMemo and attached it to an SVG element. However, when I simulate a wheel event in my Jest tests using React Testing Library, the expected zoom behavior is not triggered, and the scales are not updated as expected.

Here is a simplified version of my component and test:

```
import React, { useMemo, useRef } from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

const MyD3Component = () => {
  const svgRef = useRef(null);

  // Set up zoom behavior
  const zoomBehavior = useMemo(() => d3.zoom().on('zoom', () => {
    // ... zoom logic here ...
  }), []);

  // Attach zoom behavior to SVG
  useEffect(() => {
    const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current);
    svg.call(zoomBehavior);
  }, [zoomBehavior]);

  return (
    <svg ref={svgRef} data-testid="graph-container" width={300} height={300}>
      {/* ... */}
    </svg>
  );
};

export default MyD3Component;
```

```
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import MyD3Component from './MyD3Component';

test('zoom behavior is triggered on wheel event', () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<MyD3Component />);
  const svgElement = getByTestId('graph-container');

  fireEvent.wheel(svgElement, {
    deltaY: -100 // Simulate zoom in
  });

  // Expectations for updated zoom/scale go here...
});
```

When I run the test, the fireEvent.wheel does not seem to trigger the zoom behavior defined in my component. How can I properly simulate the wheel event to test the zoom functionality with Jest and React Testing Library?